# Azure Hadoop and Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, hadoop

I am stating a new project that needs to be portable and in some scenarios will have 100's millions of entities.

Now with Azure getting hadoop that of course got my attention for the big data scenario. But I also have the small data scenario under 1 million rows.

Entity Framework code-first is they way I see designing this but needing hadoop in the mix of course may complicate things (Entity Framework of course been used to give simpler storage providers for the smaller data sets)

Now the question is does anyone have experience in this mix?

Can anyone recommended if this is a good approach or not, if not is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working on a reasonably large system based on Entity Framework Code First, with the caveats that I have been working with EF4 and cannot upgrade to 5, that your mileage may vary and the outcomes are going to be strongly affected by what you intend to do, my experience has been that EF doesn't handle large amounts of data tremendously well, it is quite inflexible, so if you need to change its standard behaviour in some way there is a good chance you are going to end up having to hack some nasty workarounds, and performance isn't amazing. If you want to do things that aren't exactly the things that EF expects you to do, then you can run into walls.

If I was thinking of designing a relatively simple/small scale Asp.Net MVC setup, I think EF is a really good choice. For a larger scale operation where you need more flexibility or you are planning to go beyond basic operations you might find that something like NHibernate works better. I don't have experience with that, but colleagues who have worked with both tend to prefer NHibernate. ( [Brief article on the comparison](http://ayende.com/blog/4351/nhibernate-vs-entity-framework-4-0) - a bit old so EF has addressed some, but not all of the points there. It is also different by design of course. )

It may be that for more high-traffic or unusual stuff you need to roll your own data access anyway just to achieve the right performance or be able to find the right data. Unsquestionably, if you are planning to try working with EF I strongly recommend some serious prototyping just to ensure it can do what you need.